# Spring Hibernate custom validators default message from property file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've this custom spring hibernate validator and a tested message.properties file (it works) but I'm not able to set this part of code right: {EmailExists.user.default}... I mean, it doesn't get the EmailExists.user.default=blablabla var on the property file...

```
package org.andreadorigo.webapp.validators.costraints;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

import org.andreadorigo.webapp.validators.EmailExistsValidator;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailExistsValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EmailExists {

    String message() default "EmailExists.user.default";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**message_it.properties**

```
constraints.dbexists=Il valore inserito è già presente nel database
```

**hibernateContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:properties/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:properties/errors</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="it" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>



    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:properties/database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>




    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="messageInterpolator"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="messageInterpolator"
        class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
        <constructor-arg ref="resourceBundleLocator" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="resourceBundleLocator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageSource"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>





    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.andreadorigo.webapp.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post the properties file and what the actual error message you get is?

Comment: I've edited my question with the property content, by the way I don't get any error back from the compiler

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `message` that returns the default key for creating error messages if the constraint is violated should be defined as:

```
String message() default "{EmailExists.user.default}";
```

and a corresponding entry in the `message_it.properties` file:

```
EmailExists.user.default=Il valore inserito è già presente nel database
```

And you need to register the validator used to validate the @Controller methods:

```
    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="messageInterpolator"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="messageInterpolator"
        class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
        <constructor-arg ref="resourceBundleLocator" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="resourceBundleLocator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageSource"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... could it be because I've the mutlilanguage system and a messageSource like this?
'code'
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:properties/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:properties/errors</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
'code'

Comment: is it working for other constraints..i mean non-custom constraints, e.g., `@NotEmpty, @NotNull` constraints?

Comment: Only this: {EmailExists.user.default}

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this too:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/messages/validation"/>
</bean>
```

You need to get sure the file `/messages/validation.properties` exists in the classpath. If you are using Maven you can do this by putting this file in the `resources` folder (`project/src/resources/messages/validation.properties`).

Take in consideration that @Valid messages only supports win-cp1251 (ANSI) encoding by default.